# Power very large number in C++

Tags: c++, string, math

Can someone with a bit of time, he could explain to me how intensify very large numbers? I'm not talking here about a ready solution, and the only explanation of how to implement the arithmetic. Ideally, it was based on the class std::string.

@edit

I read something about shifts bit, but examples were only in the form of a listing, and I want an explanation of how it works.

Comment: Search for big integer library. However, practically no solution will be based on std::string as this is inefficient. Write your own, or stringify each number.

Comment: you must declare number as array...each element of array point to one digit of number

Comment: If you're planning on implementing our own (and you'd be crazy to, as there are plenty of implementations already out there) I would encourage you to use a vector of regular scaler for your data type and write translators for conversion to/from a `std::string`. You will find the math parts considerably easier to coalesce when you're not constantly having to do `(arg[n] - '0')` for each datum. The resulting code will be *considerably* easier to maintain.

Comment: Using `std::string` you'd do arithmetic exactly as you learned it in school. One digit at a time. Division is toughest but you don't need that to compute powers.

Comment: A very enjoyable way to learn about bignum arithmetic (and how interpreters work, too) is to study http://www.t3x.org/s9fes/ Scheme 9 from emptyspace.  The book is not free, but it's cheap. See http://www.t3x.org/s9book/.  It's great fun.  The bignum implementation sacrifices a bit of speed for very concise, understandable implementation.  When you understand this, the more sophisticated packages like `gnump` will be easier to grok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something I quickly wrote when I needed (do not remember when). It is:

1. Buggy;
2. Not complete;
3. Arbitrarily use 3 digits per array element while it could use more;
4. Can clearly be improved (any kind comments are welcome^^).

However, I hope this will be somehow useful.

```
typedef long long int lli;

class BigInt
{
public: // Methods
    BigInt(lli s) : m_nbElements(100)
    {
        m_number.resize(m_nbElements);

        for (lli i=0; i < m_nbElements; ++i)
        {
            m_number[i] = s%1000;
            s /= 1000;
        }
    }

    BigInt(const std::string &str) : m_nbElements(100)
    {
        m_number.resize(m_nbElements);

        size_t sizeStr = str.size();
        int i = str.size() - 1;
        int thousands = 0;
        for (; i >= 2; i -= 3, ++thousands)
        {
            std::string subStr = str.substr(i-2, 3);
            unsigned int value;
            std::istringstream(subStr) >> value;
            m_number[thousands] = value;
        }

        // Handle the "first" 1 or 2 digits
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            std::string subStr = str.substr(0, i+1);
            unsigned int value;
            std::istringstream(subStr) >> value;
            m_number[thousands] = value;
        }
    }

    BigInt operator*(lli s)
    {
        lli temp, remainder = 0;
        for (lli i=0; i < m_nbElements; ++i)
        {
            temp = m_number[i] * s + remainder;
            m_number[i] = temp % 1000;
            remainder = temp / 1000;
        }

        return (*this);
    }

    BigInt operator/(lli s)
    {
        lli temp, remainder = 0;
        for (int i=m_nbElements-1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            temp = (m_number[i] + remainder) / s;
            remainder = (m_number[i] % s)*1000;
            m_number[i] = temp;
        }

        return (*this);
    }

    BigInt operator-(BigInt s)
    {
        lli temp;
        for (unsigned int i=0; i < m_nbElements; ++i)
        {
            temp = m_number[i] - s.m_number[i];
            if (temp < 0)
            {
                --m_number[i+1];
                temp += 1000;
            }
            m_number[i] = temp;
        }

        return (*this);
    }

    BigInt operator+(BigInt s)
    {
        lli temp, remainder = 0;
        for (lli i=0; i < m_nbElements; ++i)
        {
            temp = m_number[i] + s.m_number[i] + remainder;
            m_number[i] = temp % 1000;
            remainder = temp / 1000;
        }

        return (*this);
    }

    std::string ToString()
    {
        std::string result = "";
        bool significantDigitsFound = false;
        for (int i=m_nbElements-1; i >= 0 ; --i)
        {
            if (!significantDigitsFound)
            {
                if (m_number[i] > 0)
                {
                    std::ostringstream ss;
                    ss << m_number[i];
                    result = ss.str();

                    significantDigitsFound = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::ostringstream ss;
                ss << std::setw(3) << std::setfill( '0' ) << m_number[i];
                result += ss.str();
            }
        }

        if (result == "")
        {
            result = "0";
        }

        return result;
    }

private: // Attributes
    int m_nbElements;
    std::vector<lli> m_number;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can represent a large number as a sequence of digits in some base, and separately the sign of the number. To do arithmetic, you simply implement the algorithms you learnt at primary school to do addition, long multiplication, etc. There's more efficient algorithms (for example Karatsuba) for doing some operations, but an initial implementation could use the simpler forms.

If you really have to use std::string, you can use the first char to store the sign ('+' or '-'), and then the digits in base 10 in ascii. It's not efficient, but it's perhaps an easy way to get started, and it certainly makes printing the numbers out easy.